# Angular Error: Model is not of type `number` for editable column

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Getting Angular Error: Model is not of type `number` for editable column.

I'm have certain editable columns of grid with type="number". when I trying to edit the cell, I'm getting this error "Error: [ngModel:numfmt] Expected `1` to be a number".

I've gone through previous posts and found that to use string-to-number in input tag to solve this. But my problem is not with the input box, it's **editable cell** on a grid.

Comment: can you post some relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing some code it's hard to propose an answer but the usual fix is to use a `string-to-number` directive on a select or input.

**directive**

```
.directive('stringToNumber', function() {
   return {
       require: 'ngModel',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
           ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
               return '' + value;
           });
           ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
               return parseFloat(value, 10);
           });
       }
   };
});
```

**html**

```
<select/input string-to-number ng-model="foo">...
```

There is very little in the way of documentation on this but you can read up on it here - https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/numfmt